# How to collapse existing content when a bottomsheet is expanded?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, coordinator-layout

I have a layout that contains a `CoordinatorLayout` with a `ScrollView` and a `BottomSheet`. When I set the state of the `BottomSheet` to expanded the `BottomSheet` overlaps the content of the `ScrollView`. I would like the height of the `ScrollView` to be reduced by the height of the `BottomSheet`. How can I achieve this?

I am going to move to using a `BottomSheetDialog` for now.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to make a solution that adjusted the layout when the bottome sheet was expanded, but ended up settling on using a BottomSheetDialog:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.html